# Laravel language file newly added strings do not work

Tags: laravel

I have a multilingual Laravel application, in which i have dashboard.php in both arabic and english language, it was working successfully until before last two days, now after i adding some new strings, it do not pick the word

in my english folder, there is a file called dashboard, which has a string like below
'reports ' => 'Reports',

but in the application it shows like " dashboard.reports "

Is there anything wrong

Here my codes in language file

```
<?php

return [

    'dashboard' => 'Dashboard',
    'total_orders' => 'Total Orders',
    'completed_orders' => 'Completed Orders',
    'total_companies' => 'Total Companies',
    'show_more' => 'show more',
    'orders' => 'Orders',
    'companies' => 'Companies',
    'profile' => 'Profile',
    'logout' => 'Logout',
    'language' => 'Language',
    'copyright' => 'copyright',
    'by' => 'by',
    'firstlogo' => 'First Logo',
    'company_creation' => 'Company Creation',
    'name' => 'Name',
    'commercial_record' => 'Commercial Record',
    'business_activity' => 'Business Activity',
    'phone' => 'Phone Number',
    'email' => 'Email Address',
    'password' => 'Password',
    'address' => 'Address',
    'website' => 'Website',
    'profit_method' => 'Profit Calcutaltion method',
    'fixed_amount' => 'Fixed Amount',
    'variable_amount' => 'Variable Amount',
    'storage_fees' => 'Storage Fees',
    'delivery_fees' => 'Delivery Fees',
    'cod_fees' => 'Cash on delivery fees',
    'username' => 'Username',
    'add' => 'Add',
    'fixed_amount_value' => 'Fixed amount value',
    'variable_amount_value' => 'Variable amount value',
    'add_company' => 'Add company',
    'second_variable_amount_value' => 'Second piece value',
    'company_added_successfully' => 'Company added successfully',
    'all_companies' => 'All companies',
    'action' => 'Action',
    'delete_confirmation' => 'Delete Confirmation',
    'are_you_sure_to_delete' => 'Are you sure to delete this company?',
    'cancel' => 'Cancel',
    'ok' => 'Ok',
    'company_deleted_successfully' => 'Company deleted successfully',
    'update_company' => 'Update Company',
    'update' => 'Update',
    'edit' => 'Edit',
    'delete' => 'Delete',
    'company_updated_successfully' => 'Company information updated successfully',
    'deleting' => 'Deleting...',
    'stock' => 'Stock',
    'products' => 'Products',
    'add_product' => 'Add product',
    'price' => 'Price',
    'company' => 'Company',
    'quantity' => 'Quantity',
    'location' => 'Location',
    'description' => 'Description',
    'product_added_successfully' => 'Product added successfully',
    'product_updated_successfully' => 'Product updated successfully',
    'product_deleted_successfully' => 'Product deleted successfully',
    'delete_product_confirmation' => 'Product delete confirmation',
    'are_you_sure_to_delete_product' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this product?',
    'product_creation' => 'Product Creation',
    'please_sign_in' => 'Please sign in to start your session',
    'login' => 'Login',
    'remember_me' => 'Remember me',
    'forgot_password' => 'Forgot your password?',
    'client_name' => 'Client name',
    'client_phone' => 'Mobile No.',
    'client_whatsapp' => 'Whatsapp No.',
    'payment_method' => 'Payment Method',
    'product' => 'Product',
    'quantity' => 'Quantity',
    'total' => 'Total amount',
    'all_orders' => 'All orders',
    'add_order' => 'Create order',
    'order_creation' => 'Order Creation',
    'online_payment' => 'Online Payment',
    'cash' => 'Cash',
    'choose' => 'Choose',
    'update_product' => 'Update product',
    'choose_company' => 'Choose company',
    'successfull' => 'Successfull..!',
    'stock' => 'Stock',
    'enter_quantity' => 'Enter quantity for ',
    'add_more' => 'Add more',
    'submit_order' => 'Submit order',
    'status' => 'Status',
    'order_total' => 'Order total',
    'order_products' => 'Order products',
    'view' => 'View',
    'invoice' => 'Invoice',
    'date' => 'Date',
    'from' => 'From',
    'to' => 'To',
    'mail' => 'Email',
    'mobile' => 'Mobile',
    'whats_app' => 'Whatsapp',
    'inv_no' => 'Inv.No',
    'net_total' => 'Net total',
    'update_order' => 'Update order',
    'sr' => 'SR',
    'clear' => 'Clear',
    'order_id ' => 'Order id',
    'pdf' => 'PDF',
    'excel' => 'EXCEL',
    'date_range_error' => 'Please select a date',
    'generate_pdf' => 'Generate PDF',
    'order' => 'Order',
    'settings' => 'Settings',
    'admin_send_mail_when_sts_change' => 'Send email when order status changed',
    'admin_send_mail_when_qty_change' => 'Send email when product quantity changed',
    'admin_get_mail_when_order_created' => 'Get email when new order created',
    'admin_send_invoice_pdf_when_order_completed' => 'Send invoice email when an order completed',
    'order_status_changed' => 'Order status changed..!',
    'order_quantity_changed' => 'Product stock updated..!',
    'view_order' => 'View order',
    'orderid ' => 'Order id',
    'new_order_created ' => 'New order created..!',
    'email_with_invoice ' => 'An order has been completed,we have attached invoice with this email',
    'order_completed ' => 'Order completed',
    'new_orders ' => 'New orders',
    'order_on_delievery ' => 'Orders on delivery',
    'this_month ' => 'This month',
    'new ' => 'New',
    'on_delivery ' => 'On delivery',
    'completed ' => 'Completed',
    'last_six_month_sales ' => 'Last six month sales',
    'Total ' => 'Total',
    'total_income ' => 'Total income',
    'income ' => 'Income',
    'preparation_fee ' => 'Preparation fee',
    'profit ' => 'Profit',
    'income_report ' => 'Income report',
    'no_orders ' => 'orders',
    'orders_report ' => 'Orders report',
    'total_payment_to_smartx ' => 'Total payment to smart-X',
    'order_profit ' => 'Order profit',
    'in_stock ' => '-In stock',
    'reports ' => 'Reports',
    'inventory_report ' => 'Inventory report',



    //error messages
    'company_name_required' => 'Please enter company name',

];
```

Comment: can you share code in blade.php file

Comment: ok, i will publish it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mutliples space inside your translation keys :
`'new ' => 'New',`
`'reports ' => 'Reports',`

Try to clean your array's key.

Comment: Fine, just approve my answer, so other will know this question is done.